# Unable to get the XSLT select id() function to work successfully

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

I'm having trouble getting the id() function to work in my xslt transformation per the example code below and I'm not sure why. When I load data.xml into a browser I'm expecting to see just the name & size values of the 'BC' item per the stylesheet/transformation.  Any suggestions?  FYI: I've adapted the example from [another site](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/XML/0100__XSLT-stylesheet/selectbyid.htm).

File: transform.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>      
            <xsl:value-of select="id('BC')/name" />
            <xsl:value-of select="id('BC')/size" />             
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

File: data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xslt" ?>

<provinces xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="data.xsd">
 <province id="AB">
  <name>Alberta</name>
  <size>33</size>
 </province>
<province id="BC">
 <name>British Columbia</name>
 <size>44</size>
</province>
<province id="MB">
 <name>Manitoba</name>
 <size>55</size>
 </province>
</provinces>
```

File: data.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="provinces">   
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="province" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>       
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="province">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name"  />
            <xs:element name="size" />  
        </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>       

 </xs:schema>
```

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: The goal is to use the XSLT processor thats in Firefox or other modern browser (I presume). Its the one that would be evaluating the stylesheet reference.  I'm not getting an explicit error when loading the xml file above so I'm assuming that the code is legit, no?  Do you think there might be something wrong with the specification in the XML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because the attribute is named id doesn't make it an ID attribute: it has to be declared as an ID in the DTD or schema (or it can be named xml:id if the processor supports that).

It's probably simplest here to switch to using key() instead.

Comment: Isn't that what I did in the schema?    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>

Comment: Tried the key() function, it works great! Seems much more flexible too. (XSLT newbie here)

Comment: @Brian: You forgot to accept the answer (Hint: click on the check-mark next to the answer). In case you were not aware of another fact: Michael Kay is the author of some best books on XSLT and XPath (both 1.0 and 2.0).

Answer (score 0):

As XSL 2.0 uses the same functions as XQuery 1.0 / XPath 2.0, you can also use the function  [`fn:element-with-id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-element-with-id). This function solves the problem that `fn:id(...)` only works with `xml:id` attributes (and not with `xs:ID`).

Read more about this here: [How to use the XQuery fn:id() function?](http://xqueryxpath.tumblr.com/post/8210950561/how-to-use-the-xquery-fnid-function).

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
<xsl:value-of select="/id('BC')/name" />
```

instead of

```
<xsl:value-of select="id('BC')/name" />
```

Comment: The two expressions are completely equivalent.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Actually, I don't think in XPath 1.0 the first expression is even syntactically legal.